# Script for backing up keyvault

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I've been trying to tweak and make a basic simple script just a bit more clean and overall to improve it.
Basically the initial script was iterating and doing a backup for each secret,certificate and key from each keyvault in a subscription.
I am trying to make it better by creating a function and trying to use it as such, unfortunately I'm still missing some thigns and I would like someone to help me sort this out:

```
function Get-Backup{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        $Item,
        [Parameter()]
        $VaultName
    )
$Items = az keyvault $Item list --vault-name $VaultName | ConvertFrom-Json
    foreach ($Item in $Items) {
        az keyvault $Item backup --vault-name $VaultName --name $Item.Name --file $Item/$Name.txt
    }
}

$Vaults = az keyvault list | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($VaultName in $Vaults) {
Get-Backup("secret",$VaultName)
Get-Backup("certificate",$VaultName)
Get-Backup("key",$VaultName)
}
```

This doesn't work, and I don't understand really what I'm missing or doing wrong. the whole point of this would be to do a script that would automatically pick all the secrets all the keys and all the certificates in a vault, and do this for each vault.

I am trying to compile a function so I could reduce the main code and rely more on functions.

Unfortunatetly I can not post the error as it contains lots of identifiable information of my subscription name resource group etc. Starts with " ERROR: '' is misspelled or not recognized by the system. "

I am looking to do this myself but being stuck for a couple of days, I'd really appreaciate some hints and help.

Comment: Did you step through your code in a debugger? The variable values are probably not what you expect them to be, and you can easily confirm or deny that in a debugger. For example, the line: `az keyvault $Item backup`. What's the value of `$Item`? You're using it like a complex object with properties a few characters later, i.e. `$Item.Name`. But then you're also trying to reference an undefined variable called `$Name` shortly after *that*: `--file $Item/$Name.txt`. You're also redefining the variable `$Item` in your function. It's both a parameter to the function and a loop iterator.

Comment: Another issue: You retrieve details about your keyvaults here: `$Vaults = az keyvault list | ConvertFrom-Json`. But then you assume that the `$Vaults` is an array of one property, the name. It's not. Again, *please* step through your code in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try solution given [here](https://zimmergren.net/backup-azure-key-vault-secrets-keys-certificates/). But please note that here you have

> risk of having in-memory variables

```
Param(
    [parameter(mandatory)] [string] $originVault,
    [parameter(mandatory)] [string] $originSubscriptionId,
    [parameter(mandatory)] [string] $destinationVault,
    [parameter(mandatory)] [string] $destinationSubscriptionId,
    [string] $disableDestinationSecrets = $true
)

# 1. Set the source subscription id. 
Write-Host "Setting origin subscription to: $($originSubscriptionId)..."
az account set -s $originSubscriptionId

# 1.1 Get all secrets
Write-Host "Listing all origin secrets from vault: $($originVault)"
$originSecretKeys = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $originVault  -o json --query "[].name"  | ConvertFrom-Json

# 1.3 Loop secrets into PSCustomObjects, making it easy to work with later.
$secretObjects = $originSecretKeys | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host " - Getting secret value for '$($_)'"
    $secret = az keyvault secret show --name $_ --vault-name $originVault -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        secretName  = $_;
        secretValue = $secret.value;
    }#endcustomobject.

}#endforeach.

Write-Host "Done fetching secrets..."

# 2. Set the destination subscription id.
Write-Host "Setting destination subscription to: $($destinationSubscriptionId)..."
az account set -s $destinationSubscriptionId

# 2.2 Loop secrets objects, and set secrets in destination vault
Write-Host "Writing all destination secrets to vault: $($destinationVault)"
$secretObjects | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host " - Setting secret value for '$($_.secretName)'"
    az keyvault secret set --vault-name $destinationVault --name "$($_.secretName)" --value  "$($_.secretValue)" --disabled $disableDestinationSecrets -o none
}

# 3. Clean up
Write-Host "Cleaning up and exiting."
Remove-Variable secretObjects
Remove-Variable originSecretKeys

Write-Host "Finished."
```

or this [one](https://rozemuller.com/disaster-recovery-plan-for-azure-key-vault-using-tags-powershell-and-azure-function/) which uses powershell instead of azure cli.

```
$storageAccountTemplateFile = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srozemuller/Azure/main/AzureStorageAccount/azuredeploy.json"
$storageAccountTemplateParameters = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/srozemuller/Azure/main/AzureStorageAccount/azuredeploy.parameters.json"
$backupFolder = "$env:Temp\KeyVaultBackup"
$location = "West Europe"

$backupLocationTag = "BackupLocation"
$backupContainerTag = "BackupContainer"

$global:parameters = @{
    resourceGroupName = "RG-PRD-Backups-001"
    location          = $location
}
function backup-keyVaultItems($keyvaultName) {
    #######Parameters
    #######Setup backup directory
    If ((test-path $backupFolder)) {
        Remove-Item $backupFolder -Recurse -Force

    }
    ####### Backup items
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$($backupFolder)\$($keyvaultName)" | Out-Null
    Write-Output "Starting backup of KeyVault to a local directory."
    ###Certificates
    $certificates = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $keyvaultName 
    foreach ($cert in $certificates) {
        Backup-AzKeyVaultCertificate -Name $cert.name -VaultName $keyvaultName -OutputFile "$backupFolder\$keyvaultName\certificate-$($cert.name)" | Out-Null
    }
    ###Secrets
    $secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyvaultName
    foreach ($secret in $secrets) {
        #Exclude any secrets automatically generated when creating a cert, as these cannot be backed up   
        if (! ($certificates.Name -contains $secret.name)) {
            Backup-AzKeyVaultSecret -Name $secret.name -VaultName $keyvaultName -OutputFile "$backupFolder\$keyvaultName\secret-$($secret.name)" | Out-Null
        }
    }
    #keys
    $keys = Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName $keyvaultName
    foreach ($kvkey in $keys) {
        #Exclude any keys automatically generated when creating a cert, as these cannot be backed up   
        if (! ($certificates.Name -contains $kvkey.name)) {
            Backup-AzKeyVaultKey -Name $kvkey.name -VaultName $keyvaultName -OutputFile "$backupFolder\$keyvaultName\key-$($kvkey.name)" | Out-Null
        }
    }
}
$keyvaults = Get-AzKeyVault 
    if ($keyvaults) {
        if ($null -eq (get-AzResourceGroup $global:parameters.resourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
            New-AzResourceGroup @global:parameters
        }
        if ($null -eq ($keyvaults | ? { $_.Tags.Keys -match $BackupLocationTag })) {
            # if no backuplocation tags is available at any of the keyVaults we will create one first
            $deployment = New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $global:parameters.resourceGroupName -TemplateUri $storageAccountTemplateFile -TemplateParameterUri $storageAccountTemplateParameters
            $backupLocation = $deployment.outputs.Get_Item("storageAccount").value
            if ($deployment.ProvisioningState -eq "Succeeded") {
                foreach ($keyvault in $keyvaults) {
                    $containerName = $keyvault.VaultName.Replace("-", $null).ToLower()
                    if (!(Get-aztag -ResourceId $keyvault.ResourceId  | ? { $_.Tags.Keys -match $BackupLocationTag }  )) {
                        Update-AzTag $keyvault.ResourceId -operation Merge -Tag @{BackupLocation = $backupLocation; BackupContainer = $containerName }
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
        else {
            foreach ($keyvault in $keyvaults) {
                $backupLocation = (get-azkeyvault -VaultName $keyvault.vaultname | ? { $_.Tags.Keys -match $BackupLocationTag}).tags.Get_Item($BackupLocationTag)
                $storageAccount = get-AzStorageAccount | ? { $_.StorageAccountName -eq $backupLocation }
                if ($null -eq (Get-aztag -ResourceId $keyvault.ResourceId  | ? { $_.Tags.Keys -match $BackupContainerTag }  )) {
                    $containerName = $keyvault.VaultName.Replace("-", $null).ToLower()
                    Update-AzTag $keyvault.ResourceId -operation Merge -Tag @{BackupContainer = $containerName }
                }
                $containerName = (get-azkeyvault -VaultName $keyvault.vaultname | ? { $_.Tags.Keys -match $backupContainerTag }).tags.Get_Item($backupContainerTag)
                if ($null -eq (Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $storageAccount.context)) {
                    New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $storageAccount.context
                }
                backup-keyVaultItems -keyvaultName $keyvault.VaultName
                foreach ($file in (get-childitem "$($backupFolder)\$($keyvault.VaultName)")) {
                    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $file.FullName -Container $containerName -Blob $file.name -Context $storageAccount.context -Force
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: marked as answer, it's something similar what I'm trying to achieve but on a way larger scale and other method of storing and stuff. but it gave me exactly the ideas I was looking for. sorry for the delay took a while to answer.

Comment: @CălimanuLoredan could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?